# SELECT statement WHERE BETWEEN calculated fields - empty results

Tags: mysql

I am having a problem with a select statement in MySQL.

I have two statements varying only slightly, the first appears to work but the second does not. The second statement returns 0 results. What am I missing/doing wrong?

### Set Variables

```
SET @maxOK = 1.2;
SET @minOK = .8;
```

## 1# NOT BETWEEN

```
SELECT *, fee - (receipts * -1) AS difference
FROM div.Data1
WHERE (receipts * -1) NOT BETWEEN (fee * @minOK) AND (fee * @maxOkay);
```

## 2# BETWEEN

```
SELECT *, fee - (receipts * -1) AS difference,
          receipts * -1 as rec,
          fee * @minOk as min, fee * @maxOk as max
FROM div.Data1
WHERE (receipts * -1) BETWEEN (fee * @minOK) AND (fee * @maxOkay);
```

## Some Data that should be showing in two but doesn't

```
SELECT *, fee - (receipts * -1) AS difference,
          receipts * -1 as rec,
          fee * @minOk as min, fee * @maxOk as max
FROM div.Data1
```

[image]

Comment: In second query you have used only BETWEEN, so there might not be any data between these values, because of which it is not showing any data.

Comment: @Rain my last sections shows data that should show up as results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your statement. You have declared `@maxOk` but are using `@maxOkay` in your `BETWEEN` clause.

As `@maxOkay`isn't declared anywhere, it's initialized to `NULL` so **your statement essentially boils down to**

```
SET @maxOK = 1.2;
SET @minOK = .8;

SELECT *
       , fee - (receipts * -1) AS difference
       , receipts * -1 as rec
       , fee * @minOk as min
       , fee * @maxOk as max
FROM Data1
WHERE (receipts * -1) BETWEEN (fee * @minOK) AND NULL
```

**The statement *should* be**

```
SET @maxOK = 1.2;
SET @minOK = .8;

SELECT *
       , fee - (receipts * -1) AS difference
       , receipts * -1 as rec
       , fee * @minOk as min
       , fee * @maxOk as max
FROM Data1
WHERE (receipts * -1) BETWEEN (fee * @minOK) AND (fee * @maxOK);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try including the where clause components in your SELECT.
 ie:

```
SELECT (fee * @minOK) as wheremin, (fee * @maxOkay) as wheremax, *, fee - (receipts * -1) AS difference, receipts * -1 as rec, fee * @minOk as min, fee * @maxOk as max FROM div.Data1 WHERE (receipts * -1) BETWEEN (fee * @minOK) AND (fee * @maxOkay);
```

Comment: That is what the min and max columns are.